# Scroll UITextView to bottom without animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have the following code which scrolls a textview to the bottom with animation.

```
- (void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView {
    [_logTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([_logTextView.text length], 0)];
}
```

I've seen some other examples that use contentOffset but that may have a bug? as it gives inconsistent results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you can try:

```
- (void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView {

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    [_logTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([_logTextView.text length], 0)];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
```

Comment: This is the much better solution - the other one stutters.

Comment: I can't get this one to work. It just scrolls 'almost to the bottom'.